# R Problem with nested JSON list and non-unique names

Tags: r, json, nested-lists

I have a deep nested list from a JSON API and run into a problem when unlisting the list because of non-unique variable identifiers in different sublists.

The same variable names mean different things in different sublists.
The sublists are this weird type of subnumbers (I don't know the proper name), meaning they don't have name identifiers but are only accessible through [[1]], ... etc. normal operators like [1:4] or [i] don't seem to work in the double brackets.

The Data comes from UN OCHAs Financial Tracking Service API. What I would like to have is a data.frame with the info on donor, recipient organization, recipient country, total amoundUS$, and cluster to which the project belonged for each flow.

```
library(httr)

# Load Sample Data ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Sample of 2001 (bigger dataloads need login)
res = GET("https://api.hpc.tools/v1/public/fts/flow?year=2001")

jsonRespParsed <- httr::content(res)

# The Problem  ---------------------------------------------------------------

# The variables sourceObjects.names revers to names in 3 different lists and leads to different results
# Long Donor Name
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$sourceObjects[[1]]$name
# Short Donor Name
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$sourceObjects[[2]]$name
# Year???
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$sourceObjects[[3]]$name

# Same for the variables destinationObjects.names 
# Name of Recipient Organization
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$destinationObjects[[1]]$name
#Cluster Name
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$destinationObjects[[2]]$name
# Recipient Country
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$destinationObjects[[3]]$name
# Year
jsonRespParsed$data$flows[[1]]$destinationObjects[[4]]$name
```

When I unlist the list and separate the nested objects, it leaves me with the problem of sourceObjects.names and destinationObjects.names. So basically, the problem is that the unlisting deletes the info about the sublist number, and without that, it becomes impossible to differentiate the duplicate variable names

```
# Unlisting the nested list  ---------------------------------------------------------------

data_raw <- enframe(unlist(jsonRespParsed))

# Getting the right number of nested sublists
rgx_split <- "\\."
n_cols_max <-
  data_raw %>%
  pull(name) %>% 
  str_split(rgx_split) %>% 
  map_dbl(~length(.)) %>% 
  max()
n_cols_max

# Separate into columns
nms_sep <- paste0("name", 1:n_cols_max)
data_sep <-
  data_raw %>% 
  tidyr::separate(name, into = nms_sep, sep = rgx_split, fill = "right")


#Ideally, I would now filter the data I need, like: 

data_filt <-
  data_sep %>%
  filter(
    (
      name3 == "method" )|
      (  name3 == "budgetYear" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "amountUSD"
      )|
      (  name3 == "sourceObjects" &
           name4 == "name" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "sourceObjects" &
           name4 == "organizationTypes" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "sourceObjects" &
           name4 == "organizationSubTypes" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "destinationObjects" &
           name4 == "name" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "destinationObjects" &
           name4 == "organizationTypes" 
      )|
      (  name3 == "destinationObjects" &
           name4 == "organizationSubTypes" 
      )
  )
```

The name repetitions makes it impossible to create a wide data.frame with columns for the values.
Please help :O

Comment: In researching this question, a feature was proposed in the purrr package to do something like this. No clear answer yet. https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/525